# read images from file in parallel

Tags: c++, image, opencv, parallel-processing

I have this function reading negative images from a dataset (approx 122000)

```
void load_images(const String & dirname, vector< Mat > & img_lst, bool showImages = false)
{
    vector< String > files;
    glob(dirname, files);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i)
    {
        Mat img = imread(files[i]); // preia imagine
        if (img.empty())            // treci peste daca este imagine invalida
        {
            cout << files[i] << " is invalid!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (showImages)
        {
            imshow("image", img);
            waitKey(1);
        }
        img_lst.push_back(img);
    }
}
```

and takes a lot of time to process and sometimes it gets blocked.
How can I optimize it and make it in parallel?

Comment: CUDA can't do file I/O, so no not maybe using CUDA

Comment: good to know thanks :)

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images in pixela? And in kB? What on earth are you planning to do with 122,000 images all in memory at once? Are your disks seriously fast and the files spread across multiple filesystems and drives? What OS are you using? How much RAM is installed?

Comment: I'm trying to train Hog, 20kb * 122000, 96X120

Comment: I guess you could try starting 4 threads in parallel see if it helps...

Comment: Is the data-set of images available somewhere - I may have a play and see if I can speed it up...

Comment: What format are the files in - JPEG, PNG?

Comment: If you do it parallel be sure to put a mutex around img_list.push_back because the push_back is not thread save.

Comment: i use this function two times once i have it png and after jpg, i m interested in my folder with jpg(there is where i have 122000 img), and is about Inria Dataset@Mark Setchell

Comment: Can you share a few images?

Comment: Which INRIA dataset? Do you have a link?

Comment: I am always keen to improve the quality and applicability of my answers, so I wondered if you had a minute to say what prompted you to accept an answer that is *harder to read and maintain* (50 lines of code and a whole new class versus 3 lines), *less portable* (only runs on Windows rather than on Windows and just about every Uniux/Linux computer in the world, less *flexible/adapted to the hardware* (always 4 threads vs adapting automatically from Raspberry Pis to supercomputers) and doesn't consider the alternative, 4-7 times less demanding (on the CPU to decode) storage format? Thank you.

Comment: Cause i'm using qt, i have an interface for all this can't compile and export nothreads, and really i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying. For future reference, you don't need to export the number of threads, it sets itself automatically according to your hardware at run-time - I only showed how to do it so you could see how I forced a specific number of threads to generate the performance graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your code a little to use OpenMP to parallelise the loading - the actual changes are minimal - I just put an OpenMP `pragma` before the `for` loop and serialised access to the vector of images since vectors are not thread safe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void load_images(int start,int end){
   vector<Mat>img_lst;
   mutex mtx;

#pragma omp parallel for
   for(size_t i=start;i<=end;i++){
      char filename[16];
      sprintf(filename,"%d.jpg",i);
      Mat img = imread(filename);
      if (img.empty()){
         cerr << "ERROR: Failed to load " << filename << endl;
      }
      mtx.lock();
      img_lst.push_back(img);
      mtx.unlock();
   }
   mtx.lock();
   cout << "INFO: Loaded " << img_lst.size() << endl;
   mtx.unlock();
}

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    load_images(1,122000);
}
```

You control the number of threads like this:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
time ./main
```

The times for loading 122,000 images varied according to the number of threads I used according to the following table:

```
Threads Time (s)
================
1       44
2       23
4       12.4
8       8.8
```

---

I then decided that, if you are doing this often enough to care, you would maybe want to pay a small price up front to improve the times yet further. So, instead of doing all that CPU-intensive code to decompress JPEGs, you might want to convert your images once, to a  more simply read format - such as [PNM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). So, I converted all the JPEG images to PNM using **GNU Parallel** and then loaded the PNM images instead:

So that looks like:

```
seq 122000 | parallel convert {}.jpg {}.pnm
```

And the code is:

```
...
...
#pragma omp parallel for
   for(size_t i=start;i<=end;i++){
      char filename[16];
      sprintf(filename,"%d.pnm",i);        <--- ONLY LINE CHANGED
      Mat img = imread(filename);
...
...
```

And you can see the times are considerably shorter:

```
Nthreads Time(s)
================
1        7
2        4
4        2.5
8        3.2
```

[image]

---

To compile with OpenMP, use:

```
g++ -fopenmp =O3 -march native ...
```

Comment: Be aware that both Mark Setchell and my solution do not store the images in the img_list array in a different order as the names in files array. So be aware of this. Solution of Mark can be simple adapted to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
class parReader
{
public:
    parReader(std::string dirname, std::vector< cv::Mat > & lst);
private:
    size_t filesIdx;
    HANDLE hFilesMux,hImgListMux;
    std::vector<cv::String> files;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> img_lst;
    static void readImgs(parReader *nm);
    const char *getNext();
    void push_back(cv::Mat &img);
};
parReader::parReader(std::string dirname, std::vector<cv::Mat> & lst) :img_lst(lst), filesIdx(0),hFilesMux(NULL),hImgListMux(NULL)
{
    hFilesMux   = CreateMutex(NULL, 0, NULL);
    hImgListMux = CreateMutex(NULL, 0, NULL);
    cv::glob(dirname, files);
    std::thread pr1(readImgs, this);
    std::thread pr2(readImgs, this);
    std::thread pr3(readImgs, this);
    std::thread pr4(readImgs, this);
    pr1.join();
    pr2.join();
    pr3.join();
    pr4.join();
    CloseHandle(hFilesMux);
    CloseHandle(hImgListMux);
}
const char *parReader::getNext()
{
    const char *res = NULL;
    WaitForSingleObject(hFilesMux, INFINITE);
    if (filesIdx < files.size())
        res = files[filesIdx++].c_str();
    ReleaseMutex(hFilesMux);
    return res;
}
void parReader::push_back(cv::Mat &img)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hImgListMux, INFINITE);
    img_lst.push_back(img);
    ReleaseMutex(hImgListMux);
}

void parReader::readImgs(parReader *nm)
{
    while (true)
    {
        const char *fn = nm->getNext();
        if (fn == NULL) break;
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(fn); 
        if (img.empty())            // treci peste daca este imagine invalida
        {
            std::cout << fn << " is invalid!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        nm->push_back(img);
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> imgList;

    parReader mgr("*.png",imgList);
}
```

tested it briefly but it should work reading images with 4 threads.